# how to strip(removed) word on perl or unix command line

Tags: perl, unix

I want to remove domain name from my device list file. I have (device.marketing.company.com) and some of them (device.company.com) on my lists of devices. I only need the device name and the ip address. so how I can strip the domain name and sub domain name from the list. and keep the device name and ip address

device1.marketing.company.com  10.1.100.12

device2.marketing.company.com  10.1.100.13

device3.marketing.company.com   10.1.100.14

device4.marketing.company.com  10.1.100.15

device5.company.com 10.1.100.16

device6.company.com 10.1.100.17

device7.company.com 10.1.100.18

The result I am looking for

device1  10.1.100.12

device2  10.1.100.13

device3   10.1.100.14

device4  10.1.100.15

device5 10.1.100.16

device6 10.1.100.17

device7 10.1.100.18

thanks,

Comment: Are you only looking for `device` as output from an input of `device.marketing.company.com`?

Comment: What is the file extension of a domain name and how does removing it give you a device name? Can you provide examples of input and output pairs?

Comment: @user559452: please up-vote answers you like and accept an answer that solves your problem.

Comment: cut -d"." -f1 ( short and nice) but call me stupid i have forget important part on my question. the device list came with IP address so I need the ip address. so now with your command strip out (.) the ip part also gone. I have corrected the question now. sorry!!! thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2

Use `sed '/\..* /s/\.[^ ]*//' ./devlist`

#### Input

```
$ cat ./devlist
device1.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.12
device2.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.13
device3.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.14
device4.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.15
device5.company.com 10.1.100.16
device6.company.com 10.1.100.17
device7.company.com 10.1.100.18
device8 10.1.100.19
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/\..* /s/\.[^ ]*//' ./devlist
device1 10.1.100.12
device2 10.1.100.13
device3 10.1.100.14
device4 10.1.100.15
device5 10.1.100.16
device6 10.1.100.17
device7 10.1.100.18
device8 10.1.100.19
```

Comment: thanks a lot appears to be working, but I am forget big thing on my question. the list is appear like this device1.marketing.company.com
device2.marketing.company.com  10.1.100.1
device3.marketing.company.com  10.1.100.2
device4.marketing.company.com  10.1.100.3 so I want to keep the ip address. I have used your command the result is device1 10 so the first 2 digit of the ip address is there but the rest is not there. your command the only one the best closes to my objective only my error is not clear on my question. again thanks much!!!

Comment: @user see my Updated answer.  This is probably the shortest code you'll get.

Comment: @user please see my Update #2 which should take care of the new requirements of having some lines without a domain name

Answer (score 0):

You could regex out the device name into a separate list. Something to the affect of "^(\w*)[.].*$"

For example if you wanted to use sed:

`sed 's/^\(\w*\)[.].*$/\1/' listfile.txt  > output.txt`

Breaking down the expression:

- **s/**   We're using sed (I honestly am
  not sure what this does)
- **^**   Starting
  the line with
- **\( \)**   Escaped
  brackets. Any pattern found between
  these can be gotten with the
  placeholder \1
- **\w***   Any alphanumeric character [A-Za-z0-9_]
- **[.]**   A literal period
- **$**     Marks the end of the line
- **/**     Separates the find pattern from the result pattern
- **\1**    Gets the placeholder for the matched pattern between the brackets **\(** and **\)**
- **/**     Ends the sed expression

Comment: You have one too many backslashes '\' in your sed code.  Instead, it should be `sed 's/^\(\w*\)[.].*$/\1/' devicename`.  Also, perhaps you already know but like using `[.]` instead, but you can get a literal period with `\.`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I was having a problem with escaping the parenthesis. It comes out different in the markup pane.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk instead of sed/cut is a better choice.

```
$ cat devicefile
device1.marketing.com
device2.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.1
device3.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.2
device4.marketing.company.com 10.1.100.3

$ awk '{split($1,a,".");$1=a[1]}1' devicefile
device1
device2 10.1.100.1
device3 10.1.100.2
device4 10.1.100.3
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this works because the shell is going to try to expand `$1`.  You should be using single quotes to surround awk code, you'll also benefit from not have to escape out any double quotes: `awk '{split($1,a,".");$1=a[1]}1' devicefile`.  Not sure why you think `awk` is the better choice though...?

Comment: awk '{sub("\\.[^ ]*","",$1)}1' is working better I think the one kurumi yes the " cause problem. regarding the sed, it'w working 90% the file but what i find out few lists on the file doesn't have any domain name just device and ip on that case sed strip the ip address part. so as command both sed and awk working but on my cause few devices don't include domain name. just on this senario awk better than sed other than that both are working. thank you so very much guys.

Comment: @SiegeX, yes, I tested the code on Windows version of gawk, hence i forgot to change back to single quotes. @user559452, pls use single quotes , see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([^.]*\)\..* \(.*\)/\1 \2/'
```

Explanation below

```
\(        #Start remembering
[^.]*     #A collection of things that don't include periods
\)        #Stop remembering
\..*      #A period, anything else, and finally a space
\(.*\)    #Remember everything after the space
/\1 \2/   #Print out the first section remembered, a space, and the second section
```